# org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect plugin error

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I am using org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect plug-in and I am having this error.

ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

```
[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
```

"org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect165525704",
  "org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect",
  "init",
  [
    "app id"
  ]
]

my cordova version is 3.5.0.

I’ve try to add appname/plugins/plugin.xml to this.

```
<feature name="FacebookConnectPlugin">
            <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin"/>
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
        <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.4.0">
            <param name="APP_ID" value="appid" />
            <param name="APP_NAME" value="appname" />
        </gap:plugin>
        <plugin name="FacebookConnectPlugin" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
```

but no luck!! I’ve Change FB.login to facebookConnectPlugin.login but again no luck..

one more thing my application use contacts to send invitations, so in my ios device, settings/privacy/contacts I can see that my application, but in Facebook I can't see my application. I I’ve already gave permission like this.

```
<feature name="FacebookConnectPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>

<plugin name="FacebookConnectPlugin" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
<access origin="https://m.facebook.com" />
<access origin="https://graph.facebook.com" />
<access origin="https://api.facebook.com" />
<access origin="https://*.fbcdn.net" />
<access origin="https://*.akamaihd.net" />

<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
</feature>
```

please help.!!!!

Comment: Are you trying to add the plugin manually? Why don't you try the cordova cli? Just google your question title for starters.

Comment: I’ve tried to use cli.. see this https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/develop. can you give any other suggestion?

Comment: Other suggestion, not really unfortunately. You don't say what happens when you try cli? By the way your link is to develop branch, I would use master if I were you.

Comment: i am having same problem if i use cli also. how can i use master branch?

Comment: you are probably using master if you use cli. The correct url is this though: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: You can post the problem to their issue log. I bet there are similar posts with possible solutions there already. just guessing..